# Check Android user's "when device is locked" notification settings

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

On Android L, I would like show the user a notification on the lock screen only if the user settings is set to "show all notification content", otherwise the content will be pointless and I just prefer not to show the notification at all.

Any idea how to verify in code the user notification settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read

```
Settings.Secure.LOCK_SCREEN_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NOTIFICATIONS = "lock_screen_allow_private_notifications"

Settings.Secure.LOCK_SCREEN_SHOW_NOTIFICATIONS = "lock_screen_show_notifications"
```

only if both are 1 then you need to show your notifications.
But since these values are not part of public api, these might change in future, or might not work on all devices

```
int show_all = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),"lock_screen_allow_private_notifications", -1); 
int noti_enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),"lock_screen_show_notifications", -1); 

if(show_all > 0 && noti_enabled > 0){
//post noti
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't check that setting as far as I know, but your app can control the level of detail visible when its notifications are displayed over the secure lock screen. To control the visibility level, call `setVisibility()` (`Notification.Builder.setVisibility`) and specify one of these values:

`VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`: Shows the notification’s full content.

`VISIBILITY_PRIVATE`: Shows basic information, such as the notification’s icon, but hides the notification’s full content.

`VISIBILITY_SECRET`: Shows nothing, excluding even the notification’s icon.

When the visibility level is `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE`, you can also provide a redacted version of the notification content that hides personal details. For example, an SMS app might display a notification that shows "You have 3 new text messages" but hides the message content and senders. To provide this alternative notification, first create the replacement notification using `Notification.Builder`. When you create the private notification object, attach the replacement notification to it through the `setPublicVersion()` method.

[Sources](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html)

Comment: I'm awake of the visibility configuration but I wanted to prevent from showing the notification and not modify the content. Thanks again!