# error: cannot find symbol variable LOCK_SCREEN_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NOTIFICATIONS

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to read the device's “when device is locked” notification settings. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768345/check-android-users-when-device-is-locked-notification-settings) answer but it seems like this is not part of a public api and I am getting the error

```
error: cannot find symbol variable LOCK_SCREEN_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NOTIFICATIONS
```

Can someone please help me resolve it? Thanks !!